# Mysql SELECT from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I can't seem to figure out how to make a SELECT statement that group products and displays the products under one product type.

I have a table called floors containing 15 different floor products and a table called floortypes containing 8 different product types (ftid) and a product image. 
Each of the 15 products have a floortype which define which type it is. Some of the products are almost the same but with different measurements which but it gives the products a different description.

Example:

```
Product: Product 1 Product type: 1
Product: Product 2 Product type: 1
Product: Product 3 Product type: 2
Product: Product 4 Product type: 2
Product: Product 5 Product type: 3
Product: Product 6 Product type: 4
```

What I want is to is the products to be displayed under a product group with 1 product image

```
Producttype 1 image
Product 1 description
Product 2 description 

Producttype 2 image
Product 3 description
Product 4 description  

Producttype 3 image
Product 5 description

Producttype 4 image
Product 6 description
```

I hope someone is able to help me!

EDIT

I used your first example which works flawlessly.
This is my final code:

```
$sql = SQLHandling::SQLquery("SELECT A.fid, A.floorname, A.desc_dk, A.floortype, B.prodimage, GROUP_CONCAT(A.desc_dk SEPARATOR '|') AS descr, GROUP_CONCAT(A.floorname SEPARATOR '|') AS fname FROM floors A JOIN floortypes B ON A.floortype = B.ftid GROUP BY A.floortype, B.prodimage");
```

and then my while loop:

```
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $delimiter = "|";
    $descr = explode($delimiter, $row["descr"]);
    $fname = explode($delimiter, $row["fname"]);

    $markers["###FLOOR###"] .= '<div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 425px; margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: left;">';    
    $markers["###FLOOR###"] .= '<p><a href="index.php?page=sfp&room='. $_GET["room"] .'&floor='. $row["floorname"] .'&wall='. $_GET["wall"] .'&envi='. $_GET["envi"] .'&fpanel='. $_GET["fpanel"] .'"><img src="images/floors/'. $row["prodimage"] .'.jpg" width="200" /></a></p>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($descr); $i++) { 
        $markers["###FLOOR###"] .= '<p><a href="index.php?page=sfp&room='. $_GET["room"] .'&floor='. $fname[$i] .'&wall='. $_GET["wall"] .'&envi='. $_GET["envi"] .'&fpanel='. $_GET["fpanel"] .'">'. $descr[$i].'</a></p>';
    }

    $markers["###FLOOR###"] .= '</div>';

    if (++$counter % 4 == 0) {
        $markers["###FLOOR###"] .=  '<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>';
    }
}
```

gives me exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are just looking for this ?

```
SELECT B.ftid, B.prodimage, A.fid, A.floorname, A.desc_dk     
FROM   floors A JOIN floortypes B 
ON     A.floortype = B.ftid
```

This will give a resultset as follows,

```
producttype1, pt1image, product1 id, product1 name, product1 descriptin
producttype1, pt1image, product2 id, product2 name, product2 descriptin
producttype2, pt2image, product3 id, product3 name, product3 descriptin
producttype2, pt2image, product4 id, product4 name, product4 descriptin
producttype3, pt3image, product5 id, product5 name, product5 descriptin
producttype4, pt4image, product6 id, product6 name, product6 descriptin
```

Comment: I fixed it! My answer is at the top! :)

Comment: Good Going Morten ! Would be great if you accept the answers if this helped you !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.producttype, B.image, Group_concat(<productid> order by <productid> SEPARATOR ',') Products
FROM   PRODUCT A JOIN producttype B
ON     A.producttype = B.producttype
GROUP  BY A.Producttype, B.image
```

replace "productid" with the actual column, your output will be

- producttype 1, image, "product 1,product 2"
- producttype 2, image, "product 3,product 4"

.... etc

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you help me a bit more? :)

I have this:

SELECT A.fid, A.floorname, A.desc_dk, A.floortype, B.prodimage, GROUP_CONCAT(A.fid ORDER BY B.ftid SEPARATOR ',') FROM floors A JOIN floortypes B ON A.floortype = B.ftid GROUP BY B.prodimage

where fid is the floor id from floors and ftid is the id from floortypes

But it still just output one product of the specific type.

Comment: Wait a minute.... If I put SELECT A.fid, A.floorname, A.desc_dk, A.floortype, B.prodimage, GROUP_CONCAT(A.desc_dk SEPARATOR ',') FROM floors A JOIN floortypes B ON A.floortype = B.ftid GROUP BY A.floortype, B.prodimage into PHPMYADMIN it seems to work fine, so I just have to figure out how to output it correctly in the while loop

Comment: I forgot AS after GROUP_CONCAT ... so if I put AS descr and echo $row["descr"] it comes out fine!

Thanks for the help :)